# IIS 6 shows "error 404" when accessing the site

Tags: php, iis, http-status-code-404

This problem is killing me!

For example, if I enter my site by using this link: http://www.example.com/index.php

it works just fine. But when using the domain name only (http://www.example.com) without the page name and extension, it gives me the "HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found."

Answer (score 1):

Your IIS 6 site hasn't been configured to use index.php as an index page. It'll be looking for index.html or default.htm or something similar, which probably doesn't exist.

From the IIS manager right-click the web site entry and click on the `Documents` tab.

Ensure the `Enable default content page` box is checked, and add `index.php` to the top of the list.

You might need to stop and restart the web site.

Comment: I have already added the index.php as a default page before asking the question, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

> This is for WCF Service.

Even I have the same issue! 
tried many ways and different options. 
I found that i have installed extra feature in **Window Features**.

Go to Control panel and find Turn windows Features on or off

check whether **

> Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core is checked!
>   if Checked **un-check** and re-boot machine.

And try now, you should be able to find your results.

If not there might be other reason. 
But this worked for me.